# How to select all member which has a given attribute name with UDA?

Tags: d

Considering an attribute which take a delegate ( predicate function as std.algorithm.filter )

```
struct Section( alias pred ){}
```

This is used to annotate a field like this:

```
struct A {
    @Section!( ( words ) =>  words[0] == '@' )
    string b;
    int c;
}
```

Field b is annotate by a delegate which return true if a string start by @ when called

So how to retrieve all field which are annotated by @Section ?

Is it possible to called at runtime his delegate with a string as parameter and know if is true or not ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how to retrieve all field which are annotated by @Section ?

First, use [`allMembers`](http://dlang.org/traits.html#allMembers) or `.tupleof` to enumerate over all the fields of the struct.

Then, enumerate over all attributes attached to each field using [`getAttributes`](http://dlang.org/traits.html#getAttributes). Check if `@Section` is present in the field.

> Is it possible to called at runtime his delegate with a string as parameter and know if is true or not ?

You should save an alias within the `Section` structure. For example:

```
struct Section(alias pred)
{
    alias fun = pred;
}
```

Then, just reference the `getAttributes` result tuple member.